# skip fetching unneeded datas in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'll make it simple..

I have 2 tables

```
=room_service=
-id
-room_id
-service_name
```

and

```
=room=
-id
-room_type
```

*a room service can have the same room_id that relies in the room table and should have different service_name

for example:

```
room_id(1)
service_name(extra person)

room_id(1)
service_name(extra person with bed)
```

now, i want to fetch all the room id's that doesn't have a service_name equal to "extra person with bed". i tried this

```
select id from room_service where service_name != "extra person with bed"
```

though it skips the id's with a service name of "extra person with bed", but it still fetches the same id that have other service name in it, so the query is useless if an id appears twice in the table

hope you guys could help

Comment: Maybe you need to normalize your database?

Comment: So room ID 1 has the service with name "extra person with bed" and another service with "some service" you query only filters the one condition not the other.

Comment: @Namphibian yup, i want the query to select the ids that exists in the table but skip it if one of its existence contains "extra person with bed"..

Comment: The query is working as expected you are only filtering out ONE of the two rows. Room ID 1 has two rows in the room_service table.

Comment: @Class actually, i think its properly normalized, ive excluded some dependencies to make the example simple like replacing the service_id with the service_name to avoid additional tables in my prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of ways you can resolve this.

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   room_service
WHERE  id NOT IN
(
      SELECT id 
      FROM   room_service 
      WHERE  service_name != "extra person with bed"
)
```

If I had table structures I would be able to show you some other ways.

Comment: it worked, just changed the 'service_name != "extra person with bed"' to 'service_name = "extra person with bed"' thanks